# Compass with Foundation 5 and Bower - compile issue

Tags: sass, bower

I am using the Compass library to compile SASS files to CSS. 
At the time of the first compilation, there are no errors, but I do not know which file is responsible for the overall style the page. After creating a new project and after using the `compass watch` was created several directories:

- bower_components
- scss
- js
- stylesheets

When I tried to change _settings.sccs placed in the folder scss nothing happened. Can anyone help explain to me this problem?

This is my config.rb file code:

```
Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Comment: Did you uncomment changed setting? Also you must run compass watch continuously.

Comment: Thx, for tip. I thought i didn't have to do it.